# Render a requestParameter in Tapestry

Tags: java, parameters, tapestry

I like to render a reqeustParameter "id" in my Tapestry Page.

Something like:

```
<span>${id}</span>
```

If I request the page with `google.com?id=1` it should render `<span>1</span>` Should be possible, but cant find a solution.

The doc suggest to use @Property in the Java-Class, but I can't import that. --> http://tapestry.formos.com/nightly/tapestry5/guide/parameters.html

thx

Comment: Also, you should start with the documentation on http://tapestry.apache.org ... the nightly builds on Formos stopped over a year ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluating query parameters is a little bit uncommon in Tapestry, but if you absolutely need them (e.g. some external process calls your page with a parameter), you can access them through the [`Request`](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/Request.html) service:

```
@Inject
private Request request;

public String getId() {
    return this.request.getParameter("id");
}
```